# how to use variable from .yml file to .py file

Tags: python, yaml

I have below two files one is .py file and other is .yml file as shown in image. In .py file I am using all variable that define in .yml file. Now I am looking for a solution about How I can pass this .yml file or how I can call or use the variables from .yml file to .py file. I have also marked my question in image to help to understand my question exactly.

Any suggestion will be very helpful.

Thanks

-> Below is abcd.py file

```
# abcd.py

import pexpect
import os
import yaml
from yaml import load
from pexpect import pxssh
import pdb


with open('/home/asdf/Desktop/test.yml', 'rb') as f:
 var=yaml.load(f.read())

def example(gw_user,gw_password,gw_host):
  child = pexpect.spawn("ssh"+" "+gw_user+"@"+gw_host,timeout=30)
  child.expect('password')
  child.sendline(gw_password)
  #child.expect(self.gw_prompt)
  print 'connection established'
  child.expect('$')
  child.sendline('cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ostinato/')
  child.expect('ostinato')
  child.sendline('python example.py')
  print 'establishing connectivity with ostinato'
  child.expect('127.0.0.1')
  child.sendline('10.0.0.3')
  child.expect('Tx')
  child.sendline('1')
  child.expect('Rx')
  child.sendline('1')
  child.expect('$')
  child.sendline('exit')
  child.interact()
  #return self.gw_user
 #pdb.set_trace()
answer=example(var[Username],var[Userpassword],var[Hostname])
print (answer)
```

-> Below is test.yml file

```
---
- Username:
      - xyz
- Userpassword:
      - ubuntu 
- Hostname:
      - 10.0.0.3
```

Also attached below screenshot for better understanding of my question.

[image]

Comment: Hi, SO deals a lot better with questions that post the code and not screen shots with it. To post your code paste it as text and use the code block tags on it for better formatting(optional since someone will edit it). Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Because of the structure of the YAML document, `yaml.load()` returns a list of dictionaries:

```
with open('test.yml') as f:
    var = yaml.load(f)

>>> var
[{'Username': ['xyz']}, {'Userpassword': ['ubuntu']}, {'Hostname': ['10.0.0.3']}]
```

This is not the most usable data structure; not only is there a list of single key dictionaries, but the values themselves are lists that must be indexed to get to their contents. A single dictionary would be more convenient so, if you are able to, you could change the YAML to:

```
---
Username: xyz
Userpassword: ubuntu 
Hostname: 10.0.0.3
```

which represents a single dictionary:

```
>>> var
{'Username': 'xyz', 'Userpassword': 'ubuntu', 'Hostname': '10.0.0.3'}
```

Now it's easy to pass these values to your function:

```
answer = example(var['Username'], var['Userpassword'], var['Hostname'])
```

---

If you can't change the YAML file, then you can first make a single dictionary out of the data, and then use that to call the function as above:

```
with open('test.yml') as f:
    var = yaml.load(f)
    var = {k:v[0] for d in var for k,v in d.items()}
    answer = example(var['Username'], var['Userpassword'], var['Hostname'])
```

Here the line `var = {k:v[0] for d in var for k,v in d.items()}` is a dictionary comprehension that converts the list of single-key dictionaries into a single multi-key dictionary.

Comment: Thank you so much @mhawke for your answer!

Comment: @dharpatel: No problem. You might want to consider accepting this answer, if it has solved your problem.